# Getting values of 2 variables and a constant based on a single equation using a 3D graph

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, graphics3d, inequalities

This is my function.

```
`g[p_, q_, c_] := 
 2^(-p*Log2[p] - 
     q*Log2[q] - (1 - p)*Log2[1 - p] - (1 - q)*
      Log2[1 - q])*(c^(p*q + (1 - p)*(1 - q)))*(1 - c)^(1 - 
     p*q - (1 - p)*(1 - q))`
```

I have graphed this function taking g as a function of p and q, I am varying c as a constant.

```
`flo=Manipulate[Plot3D[{g[p, q, c]}, {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}], {c, 0.001, 1}]`
```

[image]

How can I get values of p, q and c so that g[p,q,c]<1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot your function for given value `c=.5`(for example) with the option `RegionFunction`

```
 pic = Plot3D[  g[p, q, .5]  , {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{p, q, z}, z <= 1]]
```

[image]

With

```
points=pic[[1, 1]][[1]]
(*{{7.14286*10^-8, 7.14286*10^-8, 0.500001}, {0.0714286, 7.14286*10^-8,0.64673}, 
{0.142857, 7.14286*10^-8, 0.753498}, {0.214286,7.14286*10^-8, 0.840662},...}*)
points = pic[[1, 1]][[1]];
Graphics3D[{Point[points]}]
```

[image]

you get all the plotted points in pic!

Comment: Which version of mathematica do you use? The second part, that is the part beginning from points isnt working for me. I use 10.3. This is amazing though. I want the numerical values of these points too. What can I do further?

Comment: When I do this - `points = pic[[1, 1]][[1]]` ,I get just a single point. `{7.14286*10^-8, 7.14286*10^-8, 0.500001}`

Comment: Try `??pic` to Analyse the graphic. My version is v12

Comment: I get a list of numbers. I do think part of it is the values of p, q and c. Is there any way I can get the range for  p and q for a given c, such that g is lesser than 1?

Comment: Probably `points=pic[[1, 1]]` gives you the values `{p,q}` . `ListPlot[ points[[All,{1,2}]]]` shows the range.

Comment: Thank you! This is working! :)